# emacs version control mode line missing

Tags: emacs, visual-c++

After finally upgrading from emacs 21.x to 23.x, I've lost the version control status info from my mode line.

[emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/VC-Mode-Line.html#VC-Mode-Line) didn't turn up anything because it simply states that the status info should be there and offers no information about turning it on/off.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing there's probably a reason for keeping behind the curve, but FYI the current stable release is 24.3.

Comment: Which VCS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

what do you have set as your `vc-handled-backends` if this is blank or doesn't contain for source control tool, vc will not be enabled for that tool.

Comment: It is reported as: "vc-handled-backends is a variable defined in `vc-hooks.el'.
Its value is (RCS CVS SVN SCCS Bzr Git Hg Mtn Arch)". VC works fine. There's just nothing on the mode line that tells whether a file is under control or not.

Comment: have you changed your mode line settings?  maybe something is suppressing it there?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what operating system or revision control system you use, but it may be that emacs is not able to find the right command line program. On OSX with emacs 24.3 (from http://emacsformacosx.com/), I was able to restore the vc mode line by setting the proper path. In my case, using the mercurial binary from macports:

```
(setq-default vc-hg-program "/opt/local/bin/hg")
```

Other vcs' have similar variables `vc-git-program`, `vc-svn-program`, etc.